# Lorentz force model contradicts properties of antenae polarisation

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

A well known fact about antenna broadcast and reception is that the AC current in the antenna dictates the direction it will broadcast EM waves. So for instance a vertical antenna will not broadcast along the direction of the axis of the antenna. (Ie no waves or few waves will be emitted vertical and directly above the top of the vertical antenna.)

Basic physics of induction of AC in a conductor shows us that the magnetic field of an AC wire has its mag field rotate around the axis of a straight conductor. (Ie if the conductor is coming out of the page at you, the rotating mag field is rotating around this point either CW or CCW like hands on a clock face.)

Together these 2 above points implies any EM radiation will only be emitted at right angles to the conductor or antenna. So if you are looking at the antenna or conductor as a point coming out of the page with the AC mag field rotating around that point, all or most EM waves will radiate away from that point in circles on your page.

Yet the Lorentzian explanation for polarised light waves in Zeeman effect contradict this. Lorentz seems to ignore basic rules of radiation of EM radiation and pretend a vertical antenna or conductor will radiate waves vertically. (He does this by saying that his ion is rotating in circles on the page but broadcasting directly out of the page at you, which of course contradicts all observations.) How does Lorentz get a rotating source like his ion (later called electron) to broadcast at right angles to the plane of rotation?

Comment: > *"Yet the Lorentzian explanation for polarised light waves in Zeeman effect contradict this. Lorentz seems to ignore basic rules of radiation of emr and pretend a vertical antenna or conductor will radiate waves vertically."* Citation? The Lorentz theory of the Zeeman effect does not work with antenna/conductor, it works with moving charged particle.

Comment: Fact1:The Zeeman effect is explained in 1897 by Lorentz as a rotating ion Which he said gives off electromagnetic radiation perpendicular to its plane of rotation.Fact2: Notice an antenna also emits em radiation. Fact3: A vertical antenna does not emit radio waves parallel to its length,(ie it does not radiate waves straight up from the top of the antenna) Notice all the above facts are true and can be confirmed in any reliable reference. Notice that these above 3 facts show us that Lorentz ion cannot radiate perpendicular to rotation & thus LET,and anything based on it QT ,...is incorrect.

Comment: Rotating ion is not a dipole antenna. Charged particle orbiting in a plane can and does radiate in direction perpendicular to that plane.

Comment: A source for „He (Lorentz) does this by saying that his ion is rotating in circles on the page but broadcasting directly out of the page at you…“?

Comment: Holger and Jan. Below is link to original 1897 Zeeman paper page 339 in particular describes motion of ion. According to Lorentz the ion will emit em radiation perpendicular to its field of rotation. This is impossible according to current observations of broadcast antenna which ARE also emitting emr. These antenna are observed to NOT emit radiation perpendicular to the antenna atoms magnetic fields rotations. Look below: section marked radiation pattern and gain. It clearly states no radiation from top or bottom of antenna https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole_antenna
So Lorentz was wrong.